# Redis.io Vs Azure Redis cache in .Net

Tags: redis, azure-redis-cache, redis-cache

Is there any difference between Azure redis cache and redis.io , If I have Azure Subscription, I need to purchase seperate plan for Azure Redis.

IF have a difference ? When to Use Azure redis vs Redis.io.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Redis Cache is a Managed Azure service, which creates and manages the Redis instance(s) (updates, automatic failover etc.) on behalf of the customer and provides the customer with TCP endpoint(s) to communicate with. It ultimately consists of one or more instances of Redis (as described in redis.io) server, however the customer doesn't have access to the physical VMs as the service is a managed service. Various management operations are available via the Azure portal or the Management interfaces. Details are here: [Azure Redis Cache sevice](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cache/).

There shouldn't be any difference in Redis functionality between what you see on redis.io and the Azure Redis service.

Once you have an Azure subscription, you pay for the Azure services that you use based on their pricing. The pricing details for the Azure Redis Cache service are here: [Azure Redis Cache Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cache/)